# What are the deepest/darkest levels of user rights in a web/desktop application?

Tags: permissions

What would be the deepest possible level of user rights in a web/desktop application?
Is it defining the buttons on a form, columns/rows/cells of the datagrid, or table rows in the DB?
What are the possible ways of maintaining that structure?
How to limit/restrict specific cell of a datagrid per user?

Comment: @mcdowell ok, if you say so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by deepest you mean "most granular, lowest level type of security possible", then I would speculate that code access security would be the the lowest level of security possible. If by deepest you're referring to standard end-user security rights, then the answer to that is, it completely depends on the application. User permissions are usually more granular than user roles for most applications. Permissions are normally assigned to roles. But application developers can create any security access scheme that they wish.

Many applications implement various forms of data access security. For example, Ebay ensures that only you can view and edit your credit card data.

For your extremely broad question of "how to limit/restrict specific cell of a datagrid per user", there are many programmatic approaches that you can take to implement data access security. The more specific your questions are, the more specific answers can be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in trouble if your authorization model goes down to the button or grid level on a UI.

I can see where different users have different authorizations (e.g., admins with write access versus users with read-only), but it should be at a higher level than buttons and grid cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because you have asked many questions with varying complexity.

Users may have rights to do anything you want to allow them to do.  read only is an option - like on static web pages.  if it is a database question, then table visibility comes next, then rows within that table, then finally attributes on those rows.  each layer can get a variety of privilege: DELETE INSERT UPDATE SELECT or ALTER.

You are then free to think up additional functionality for your site, like the UI, and assign whatever privieges you want to that layer.  like pick my layout preferences, all the way down to drag and drop my own widget set.

totally up to you.